# How to show Ag Grid Bar Sparkline in RTL (Right to Left)

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Anyone have suggestion or ever worked on Ag grid sparkline bar chart

From this example we can display `% Bars` in Left to Right direction but I have another column for the same category to show `% Bars` in Right to Left direction, so that two percentages can be compared

Example:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/sparklines-bar-customisation/#example-bar-sparkline-progress-bars

I want to show exactly above in rever direction for another column

Answer (score 1):

I have explored few options in the AgGrid for this kind of implementation but could not find anything specific. So I got a work around to solve this problem, by changing the data shape a bit to show bars left to right & right to left, where these columns will be next to each other to compare.

After few hours of investigation, created the sample, which is as below.
The code does the trick is defining the right `data` & `valueAxiDomain` prop in the ColDefs

**Output:**
[image]

**Code**

```
  ----data.js---
  ***right to left bar***
  change: [40]
  
  ***left to right bar***
  change: [-20]


  ----index.jsx-----   
  ***left to right bar*** 
  valueAxisDomain: [0, 40],
  ***right to left bar*** 
  valueAxisDomain: [-40, 0],
```

**Working Version**: [Ag grid with Bar SparkLine Comparison](https://plnkr.co/edit/N6OomUmuaXbgHX1e?open=index.jsx&preview)

Comment: nice approach! Instead of modifying the data shape, I would recommend using column `valueGetter`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can skip labels or put labels in a separate column, then with css `transform: scaleX(-1)` it flips the bar horizontally.

Comment: Thanks @mashi  for the suggestion. But I was trying for all the edge cases